# Using a postdoc to gain key skills before taking on an industry job

Tags: job-search, job-change, applications, skills

I am nearing the end of my PhD in mechanical engineering (in the UK). Unfortunately, I don't see myself working as a mechanical engineer since my general interests and focus during the PhD was on programming/maths rather than design/management, and I don't see myself working in academia due to the low salaries/temp contracts. I am however interested in engineering careers with a heavy R&D component/data science/quant jobs in the finance sector.

I have come across an interdisciplinary postdoc in a math department which couples much of what I was working on during my PhD with machine/deep learning methods (I currently have no experience with ML) which seems to be a useful & hot skill for the industry (and the postdoc is a fairly exciting, albeit very low paid, opportunity). Is it wise to take this postdoc on to gain these skills or should I just leave for the industry after I finish my PhD given my long-term goals?

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace :) please take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to familiarize yourself with the site, and so you can learn your ways here and what things are on-topic to ask.

Comment: Do you have an offer to get this postdoc position or are you just pondering whether you should apply? From the emplyoer perspective it doesn't seem attrractive to hire you for it.  You only have part of the required skills and intend to use it primarily to learn skills instead of doing research.

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion is that Real World experience is far more valuable than University.

Plus, you are no longer paying for University but earning.

If you are interested in those fields, you can find out about them on your own time when working and then find ways to incorporate them into your paid work, gaining experience and skills on the company dime.

If you are good enough, the Company may even pay you to attend training courses.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wise to take this postdoc

No. You already know what you want to do. Focus on the most direct path and avoid any detours.

Here is why:

1. Most of the technical stuff doesn't translate well. University often teaches stuff a certain professor is interested in, but no one in the real world really cares about and that has little practical value. In fact many universities teach woefully behind the state of the art since there is no incentive for them to update their curriculum.
2. While you are doing research, the people you will be competing with for jobs are getting highly valuable hands-on experience in a commercial environment.
3. Specialized technical skills come and go out of fashion quickly. Once you have a solid understanding of the fundamentals (which is indeed extremely important), going deeper doesn't have any lasting value. In three years you will have to learn the "new cool technology" anyway, regardless of how long you stay in school.
4. Unless you get properly paid, you are loosing a lot of money and earning potential.

I spent 8 years in academia including 3 years as a post doc before I realized that I didn't want to become a professor and I jumped into industry. I was lucky enough to get competitively paid for those 8 years, otherwise I wouldn't have done it. Since I did a lot of management stuff in academia (hiring, people management, grant management, project leader) some skills where useful but many where not. After 2 years in, no one cares anymore if you have a PhD or not, and after 5 years your entire educational background becomes just a check box.

When hiring a candidate you always look at the mix of technical skills and business/soft skills. You already very high on the technical side but have little credible experience on the other. Going for a post doc would make this even worse. You'd be working on the wrong problem UNLESS there is clear evidence that your technical mix is a home run (which is unlikely).